# Trigger to allow updates, inserts only if more than 5 seconds pass since previous update or insert on this table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created a Trigger to allow updates on Customer table only between 8am and 5 pm. But now I want to make sure that there is no update/insert within 5 secs of the previous update/insert. Can I accommodate this condition in the same Trigger or do I need to create another Trigger. Anyways, can you guide me how to go about it. I am working on sql server.

```
`Create trigger tr_delete_Cust
      On dbo.Customer FOR Delete 
      AS
      IF convert(datetime2, 'hh24') < '8' OR
         Convert(datetime2, 'hh24') > '17' 
     BEGIN
         RAISERROR('Data cannot be modified at this time!',1600,16,1)
      END`
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem like valid trigger for SQL Server, you're probably looking something like this:

```
IF (datepart(hour, getdate()) < 8 OR
    datepart(hour, getdate()) > 17) begin ...
```

Your trigger seems to be just for deletes, so you'll need either this to handle also updates and inserts or create a new triggers for those.

To check how much time has passed, I'd say the best option is to have  a column in the table for update / insert time, and check max value from it. If there's a lot of rows in the table you'll might want to index that field too.